# validation in javascript for escape sequence

Tags: javascript

I have textBox which accept alphabeti want to validate the textBox contain proper Drive Path or not using javascript

ex:Suppose Textbox contain 'D:\' then it's valid or else it's invalid...I need to check textbox contain ':\' or not after alphabet

plz help me

Answer (score 1):

try to use javascript method "replace" http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp to remove unwanted contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex

```
/^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))(\\)?$/
```